# how do I create a pysimplegui that runs without needing minimized / runs in the background?

Tags: pysimplegui

I am working on a background changing program however one of the things I decided I'd do was make it, so the program / GUI runs in the background instead of needing minimized. Any examples or ideas of how I could do that?

Comment: Set option `alpha_channel` to 0 or `location` to out of screen, `no_titlebar=True`.